# Create fake seasonal dates and insert into a df

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Assume I have dataset named `df` with a unique row for each registered user (with hundreds of thousands of records).
I would like to synthetically create a new column named `registration_date` that will follow the requirements:

1. Dates should be between Jan-21 and the end of Feb-23
2. If I aggregate the dataset monthly and count the number of registered users, I would like to see an increase over time. Meaning each month is randomly somewhat better (e.g. 1%-10%) than the previous month
3. Insert some seasonal factor such as a 10%-15% M/M decrease every December

Comment: please show us what you have tried already

Answer (score -1):

Good morning my friend, I set up a simple one here by jupyter notebook, I followed the steps you went through, I hope I arrived, in the correct context.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index_date = pd.date_range(start='01/01/2021', end='01/02/2023', freq='D')

values = {'registration': np.random.randint(500 , size=732)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=index_date)

df

df['2021-12-01':'2021-12-15'] = df['2021-12-01':'2021-12-15'] - 300
df['2022-12-01':'2022-12-15'] = df['2022-12-01':'2022-12-15'] - 300
df['2021-12-16':'2021-12-31'] = df['2021-12-16':'2021-12-31'] - 115
df['2022-12-16':'2022-12-31'] = df['2022-12-16':'2022-12-31'] - 115

import matplotlib as plt

df.plot()
```